# Why is the $\chi^{2}$ approximation for deviance GLM $\sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n_{i},\pi_{i})$ not valid when $n_{i} = 1$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, generalized-linear-model, chi-squared-test, deviance

I know from McCullagh & Nelder's text (p.118) that the $\chi^{2}$ approximation for deviance for the binomial family is based on a limiting operation in which $n$, the number of observations, is fixed and $n_{i} \rightarrow \infty$ for each $i$.

How can I explain that the $\chi^{2}$ approximation for deviance is not valid when $n_{i} = 1$ clearly?

Is it simply that for 'big' $n_{i}$ that the approximation would hold?